# Conditions and correct interpretation of Borel summation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, asymptotics, power-series

Hello to the community.

In my line of research (theoretical particle physics) it is customary to apply the strategy of Borel summation to infinite power series in order to find closed forms and/or numerical estimates. However, I have the feeling things are often not done very rigurously, so I want to see if the mathematicians here can help me understand how it works.

I have a power series $R(x)\equiv\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}r_nx^n$ that I rewritte using the integral definition of the gamma function as

$$R(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{r_{n+1}}{n!}x^{n+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^n.$$

So far so good, but now people do two things.

1. The sum and the integral cannot be in general interchanged, so they define the Borel sum of the series as

   $$
   R_B(x)\equiv\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{r_{n+1}}{n!}x^{n+1}t^n.
   $$
2. They are only interested in $x>0$, so they define $u\equiv xt$ and rewrite $R_B$ as (the integration limits remain unaltered)

   $$
   R_B(x)\equiv\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u/x}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{r_{n+1}}{n!}u^n.
   $$

The series in the integrand is referred to as the Borel transform of the original series and denoted as $B[R(x)](u)$.

In my field, this strategy is tipically used for series where $r_n$ diverges factorially for large $n$. Since the series is (or is related to) a physical magnitude, we assume that, despite divergent, the series must constitute an asymptotic expansion of some unknown function. We perform the Borel transform of the series, sum the result up, and then perform the integral, and the result is interpreted as an estimate of the said unknown function.

My questions are:

1. When is $R_B(x)$ equal to $R(x)$? This is, when can the sum and the integral be interchanged?
2. If $B[R(x)](u)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{r_{n+1}}{n!}u^n$ converges for $|u|<r<\infty$ can we still integrate the result from $u=0$ to $\infty$?
3. If the original series has a finite convergence radius, how is $R_B(x)$ going to carry that information? There is an example in wikipedia on how Borel summation is applied to the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$. The original series is converges to $1/(1-x)$ for $|x|<1$, and the integral returns the same expression but under the weaker condition $\mathrm{Re}(x)<1$. It says then that Borel summation provides "an analytical contnuation of the known result "$1/(1-x)$". What does this mean exactly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe in the tag part you could add analysis to exchange your question with more people

Comment: Good advice, thanks!

Comment: You may be interested in the [Nevanlinna–Sokal theorem](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.524408). See also [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/spmj/2010-21-06/S1061-0022-2010-01125-7/S1061-0022-2010-01125-7.pdf).